# Static array variable of another class' objects does not allow calling methods of the second class

Tags: php

I am can't figure out why this doesn't work:

```
class Test
{
    public static $arData=array();

    public static function addMember(Person $member)
    {
        self::$arData[]=$member;
    }
    public static function showAll()
    {
        for($i=0;$i<count(self::$arData);$i++)
        {
            self::$arData[i]->show();
        }
    }
}
```

What I get is this: `Fatal error: Call to a member function show() on a non-object`.
The `show()` method does exist and it basically prints out name and location of a person.

In in the constructor, instead of adding $member to $arData I do $member->show() it works.

So... what's up?

Comment: read the first answer of this question just to start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891301/top-bad-practices-in-php

Comment: what do you get if you do `print_r(self::$arData)` in show all rather going through the loop?

Comment: I know yes, it's just an example.

Comment: Ian: I get an array of Person Objects with [name:private] and [location:private] for each element added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
self::$arData[$i]->show();
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
foreach (self::$arData as $person) {
    $person->show();
}
```

Comment: That would have bypassed the missing `$` sign in front of the `i`. Thanks.

Comment: It also avoids counting the array in every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the `for`-loop:

```
...
public static function showAll()
{
    for($i=0;$i<count(self::$arData);$i++)
    {
        self::$arData[$i]->show();
    }
}
...
```

It must be `$i` and not only `i` in the array-access-operator when calling the `show()`-method.

Comment: Unbelievable... thank you Stefan.